# XSLT to nest an element depending on it's name XML

Tags: xml, xslt, nested, transform

I want to nest an element within another element depending on the original element's name.

Here is my current XML;

```
<order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="">
<Replace>true</Replace>
<job_description>TESTING</job_description>
<order_qty>20000</order_qty>
<finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
<depth>10</depth>
<width>8</width>
<cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
<text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
<delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
<delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
<job_site>DG</job_site>
<managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
<is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
</order>
<master_version>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
```

"master_version" needs to be nested in "orders", however there are other elements in the XML that I don't want nested, so how would I conditionally nest "master_version"?

I've googled the problem for a while now and I can't seem to find anything that applies to me. I am new to using XML and XSLT so I may have just not understood it.

Thanks for all your help guys!

Also as a side note, my current XSLT changes the node "Replace" to an attribute of "order", however it leaves it as the above? Here is the part of the XSLT that does that;

```
<!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </order>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace"/>
```

EDIT:

I've tried this XSLT and unfortunately it looks no different;

```
<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::job_id|self::site_code|self::replace)"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::master_version[1]"/> 
    </order>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | master_version"/>
```

I wish for the output to look like this;

```
<order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="">
<Replace>true</Replace>
<job_description>TESTING</job_description>
<order_qty>20000</order_qty>
<finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
<depth>10</depth>
<width>8</width>
<cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
<text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
<delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
<delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
<job_site>DG</job_site>
<managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
<is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
<master_version>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
</order>
```

EDIT AGAIN;

Now that I've fixed the above problem, my XML is now doing this..

I have the following XSLT;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- removes the unrelated elements -->

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
<xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
<xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
<xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
<xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
<xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>

<!-- removes specified nodes from all elements -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
<xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
<xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
<xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>

<!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>



<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>



<xsl:template match="@*|node()">

    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </order>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | master_version"/>



<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../master_version"/>
    </order>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Replace | master_version"/>


<!-- renames element to specified name -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
        <xsl:element name="task_info1">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
        <xsl:element name="task_info2">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML should look like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot generated="2015-01-07T14:06:55" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<order job_id="" site_code="" replace="true">
<job_description>TESTDATA</job_description>
<order_qty>1900</order_qty>
<finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
<depth>10</depth>
<width>8</width>
<cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
<text_pagination>12</text_pagination>
<delivery_commence_date>15/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
<delivery_complete_date>15/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
<job_site>DG</job_site>
<managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
<is_managing_printer>TRUE</is_managing_printer>
<cust_order_ref>776031</cust_order_ref>
<cust_code>Test</cust_code>
<site_cce_name>Jamie</site_cce_name>
<site_cce_email>JamesBrace@dstoutput.co.uk</site_cce_email>
<sales_person_name>Jamie Brace</sales_person_name>
<sales_person_email>JamesBrace@dstouput.co.uk</sales_person_email>
<master_version>
<version_id></version_id>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>Common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
</order>
```

But it looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot generated="2015-01-07T14:06:55" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<order job_id="" site_code="" replace="true">
<job_description>TESTDATA</job_description>
<order_qty>1900</order_qty>
<finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
<depth>10</depth>
<width>8</width>
<cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
<text_pagination>12</text_pagination>
<delivery_commence_date>15/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
<delivery_complete_date>15/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
<job_site>DG</job_site>
<managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
<is_managing_printer>TRUE</is_managing_printer>
<cust_order_ref>776031</cust_order_ref>
<cust_code>Test</cust_code>
<site_cce_name>Jamie</site_cce_name>
<site_cce_email>JamesBrace@dstoutput.co.uk</site_cce_email>
<sales_person_name>Jamie Brace</sales_person_name>
<sales_person_email>JamesBrace@dstouput.co.uk</sales_person_email>
<master_version>
<ORDER>1</ORDER>
<version_id></version_id>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>Common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
<ORDER>2</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>TRUE</version_common>
<version_finished>FALSE</version_finished>
<version_description>Common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>1900</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also post what you expect as output XML? Thx.

Comment: "*"master_version" needs to be nested in "orders", however there are other elements in the XML that I don't want nested, so how would I conditionally nest "master_version"?*" This part is not clear. What is the condition?

Comment: Edited. Also the condition is that the element is called "master_version". I haven't posted the full XML, as it would take up a lot of space, but there are other elements and I only want the "master_version" element nested into "order"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a **well-formed(!) input**:

```
<root>
  <order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="">
    <Replace>true</Replace>
    <job_description>TESTING</job_description>
    <order_qty>20000</order_qty>
    <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
    <depth>10</depth>
    <width>8</width>
    <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
    <text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
    <delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
    <delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
    <job_site>DG</job_site>
    <managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
    <is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
  </order>
  <master_version>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>true</version_common>
    <version_finished>false</version_finished>
    <version_description>common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
  </master_version>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../master_version"/>
    </order>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Replace | master_version"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="true">
    <job_description>TESTING</job_description>
    <order_qty>20000</order_qty>
    <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
    <depth>10</depth>
    <width>8</width>
    <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
    <text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
    <delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
    <delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
    <job_site>DG</job_site>
    <managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
    <is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
    <master_version>
      <version_code>COMM</version_code>
      <version_common>true</version_common>
      <version_finished>false</version_finished>
      <version_description>common</version_description>
      <version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
      <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
    </master_version>
  </order>
</root>
```

Comment: yep, that's got it, thank you! however, now I'm having another problem, the part of the XSL that says to delete certain elements isn't deleting the specified "master_version" elements! I'll edit the question to explain.

Comment: I am afraid your edited XSLT makes no sense to me. You have the same identity transform template 4 or more times, and at least 2 templates that match "order". This is not a soup, not everything goes into the pot.

Comment: sorry, I really am inexperienced with this. How would you format it?

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </order>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::job_id|self::site_code|self::replace)"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::master_version[1]"/> 
    </order>
</xsl:template>
```

and then add `<xsl:template match="master_version"/>` you get the nesting, assuming it should be done for the following sibling `master_version` element and not based on some reference value.